# Highcharts Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'chart.yAxis')

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to update a chart after I receive success from an ajax call, but I'm getting this error:  `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'chart.yAxis')`. I'm pretty sure I'm calling the update method correctly. Any ideas? Is the scope of chart affected? it is defined when I check it.

```
var chart = .... chart ....
$('button#glucose_goals').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'glucose/goals',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form#glucose_boundary_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            chart.yAxis[0].update({ plotBands: [] });
            chart.redraw();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you show how do you create the chart? For me it seems that `chart` variable doesn't store chart object, but probably jQuery object. Try: `chart.highcharts().yAxis[0].update({ ... });`.

Answer (score 1):

You trimmed few lines of your code.
[here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/rtzofb0s/1/)

```
 $('#update1').click(function () {
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
plotBands: [{
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: 144,
            to: 176,
            id: 'plotband-1'
        }]
    });

});
```